# String parameter using subprocess module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Python to simplify some commands in [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/). I have this script which calls `mvn test` in debug mode.

```
from subprocess import call
commands = []
commands.append("mvn")
commands.append("test")
commands.append("-Dmaven.surefire.debug=\"-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8000 -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE\"")
call(commands)
```

The problem is with line `-Dmaven.surefire.debug` which accepts parameter which has to be in quotas and I don't know how to do that correctly. It looks fine when I print this list but when I run the script I get `Error translating CommandLine` and the debugging line is never executed.

Comment: already tried to without `\"` (no `"` in third arg)?

Comment: Yes, I've tried few quotas combinations (and also without them)

Comment: did you tried splitting the commands.append at space in your string ?

Comment: @Gcmalloc The "`" serve to protect the spaces, so splitting at the spaces seems inappropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotas are only required for the shell executing the command.

If you do the said call directly from the shell, you probably do

```
mvn test -Dmaven.surefire.debug="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8000 -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE"
```

With these `"` signs you (simply spoken) tell the shell to ignore the spaces within.

The program is called with the arguments

```
mvn
test
-Dmaven.surefire.debug=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8000 -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE
```

so

```
from subprocess import call
commands = []
commands.append("mvn")
commands.append("test")
commands.append("-Dmaven.surefire.debug=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8000 -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE")
call(commands)
```

should be the way to go.

Comment: Yeah, it really works, I must have made a typo when I was trying it. Thanks!